# How to convert a pydub `AudioSegment` for streaming purposes without an intermediate audio file?

Tags: python, audio, streaming, pydub

I'm working on a software to stream audio from a source over HTTP using a Flask webservice. I can get the sound frames through `sounddevice` and route them to a browser through a Flask route with `yield` and the right mimetype, but the raw audio format is quite cumbersome for remote streaming, and not really the best when it comes to client compatibility.

I'd love to use `pydub` to convert the raw audio frames to a format like mp3 or ogg, but it's not clear to me neither from [the documentation](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown) nor from [the source code](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/audio_segment.py) how to achieve an on-the-fly format conversion without dumping the output to a file through `.export()`.

The skeleton of my code so far is something like:

```py
### audio.py

import queue
import sounddevice as sd
from pydub.audio_segment import AudioSegment


def input_stream(device, sample_width=2, sample_rate=44100,
        channels=1, latency=0, blocksize=2048, timeout=5.0):
    audio_queue = queue.Queue()

    def audio_callback(indata, frames, time_duration, status):
        audio = AudioSegment(indata, sample_width=sample_width,
                channels=channels, frame_rate=sample_rate)

        # Some pydub magic should happen here to convert the raw frame to mp3/ogg

        audio_queue.put(audio.raw_data)


    with sd.InputStream(samplerate=sample_rate, device=device,
                        channels=channels, callback=audio_callback,
                        latency=latency, blocksize=blocksize):
        while not recording_terminated():
            yield audio_queue.get(block=True, timeout=timeout)


### web.py

from flask import route, request, Response

from audio import input_stream


@route('/sound/stream', methods=['GET'])
def get_sound_feed():
    device = request.args.get('device')
    return Response(input_stream(device), mimetype='audio/ogg')
```

How would one convert the raw `AudioSegment` object in `audio_callback` into a compressed mp3/ogg suitable for web streaming? I know that it's possible to create a segment from an mp3 through `AudioSegment.from_file`, or dump it to an mp3 file through `.export()`, but that wouldn't really be an option as such I/O operations would introduce non-negligible latency. I think it *might* be theoretically possible to hack `.export()` to get it to dump to a socket or fifo file descriptor, but that sounds a bit as a hacky workaround to me, plus I'm not sure whether it's sufficient for the file descriptor to provide the `.write()` method or if it'd break because other methods (e.g. `seek`) are required.

Comment: I've bumped into this question from 2014: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469161/how-to-convert-wav-to-mp3-in-live-using-python. The last comment seems to confirm my suspicion that exporting on-the-fly (not to a file) is not an option in pydub. I'm not sure if any progress has been made in the meantime or if some user has already made a fork to support it. If that's not the case, I might give it a try and submit a PR to pydub.

Comment: have you found how to do this? I'm trying to save the file in a BytesIO to remove the persistence aspect

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can prevent pydub from saving the file to the disk, but you can just get the file at the end of conversion without reopen it.
Actually, the `.export()` function return the file object at the end of execution.

```py
convert_file = audio_file.export(format="flac")
```

I have done this and I could process the convert_file as if I had used the `open()` function. (I convert to flac for my own project but you can do any format)
I found out that if you don't provide a file name, the `.export()` function wont even write the file to disk without any errors.
I hope you can found a workaround for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested.
One can use a BytesIO object to export a converted file into an in-memory object.

```
# Load input song
song = from_mp3("my_song.mp3")
# create new empty BytesIO
exported_io = BytesIO()
# export to BytesIO object
song.export(exported_io, format="wav")
```

One can then perform any action on this BytesIO object. No file will be created using this approach.